# How to get customerId on sales_order_place_after observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order

I'm trying to get the CustomerId when an order is placed so that I can manipulate it before the order is saved to the DB.

Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="VendorModule" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Order\Order"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Vendor/Module/Observer/Order/Order.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class Order implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_logger;
    protected $order;

    /**
     * Order constructor.
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $_logger
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $_logger,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $_logger;
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
        $this->_logger->info('Customer ID is' . $customerId);

        if ($customerId !== 0) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

This does not even log anything to var/log/debug.log
How would I get the customerId on sales_order_place_after observer?

UPDATE

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Order;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class Order implements ObserverInterface
{
    private $logger;
    private $order;
    private $customer;

    /**
     * Order constructor.
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customer
     *
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customer
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->order = $order;
        $this->customer = $customer;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        //$customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
        $customer = $this->customer;
        $customerName = $customer->getName();
        $this->logger->info('Customer name is' . $customerName);

        if ($customerName !== "Tom") {
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that `sales_order_place_after` is running for your case.The code is ok seems from end

Comment: Have you checked error log? Is website in developer mode? Can you please write die(); in the starting of execute function? And can you please try to place order again?

Comment: @ZealousWeb  Even if I write die(); in the starting of the function, I can still place orders. That's why I think sales_order_place_after isn't called at all. Could this be a bug in Magento 2.4.2? Could you please try if you can call the event at all? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take the customer ID from session. In the same observer class, inject `Magento\Customer\Model\Session` into the constructor and save it in a private property, say `$session` and use it like this:

```php
$this->session->getCustomerId()
```

***Sidenotes***

- you don't need to initialize the order object in the constructor in your above code
- your observer's properties should be private and naming without 'underscore' as per PSR-2

Comment: Thanks, could you please check the update. It seems like sales_order_place_after does not run at all after placing an order because it does not do anything.

Comment: Try changing the event into `checkout_submit_all_after`.

Comment: Nope, not working.

Comment: maybe redundant, but please make sure that your debug logging settings are enabled in admin, correct permissions are set and i would suggest you use a debugger and see if indeed it doesn't 'enter' your observer.